# Ruby loops and classes; splitting a string into an array and back to a string again

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, class, loops, split

Ruby newbie here working on loops with classes. I was supposed create a method that would take a string and add exclamation points to the end of each word (by making it an array with .split) and join the 'exclaimed' words as a string again. I've been at this for two hours already and decided I should seek help. I have a handful of ideas but I keep coming up with a NoMethod error. Below is one of ways that made sense to me but of course, it doesn't work. I've also added specs at the very end.

```
class StringModifier
  attr_accessor :string
  def initialize(string)
    @string = string
  end

  def proclaim
    new_array = []
    string.split.each do |word|
      new array = "#{word}!"
        new_array.join
    end
    new_array
  end
end
```

SPECS

```
describe StringModifier do
  describe "#proclaim" do
    it "adds an exclamation mark after each word" do
      blitzkrieg_bop = StringModifier.new("Hey ho let's go").proclaim
      expect(blitzkrieg_bop).to eq("Hey! ho! let's! go!")
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: `new array = "#{word}!"` is a typo? It should be `new_array = "#{word}!"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write your method as:

```
def proclaim
  string.split.map { |word| "#{word}!" }.join(" ")
end
```

Or write it as :

```
def proclaim
  a = string.split
  ("%s! " * a.size % a).strip
end
```

Tested :

```
[30] pry(main)> a = "Hey ho let's go".split
=> ["Hey", "ho", "let's", "go"]
[31] pry(main)> ("%s! " * a.size % a).strip
=> "Hey! ho! let's! go!"
[32] pry(main)>
```

Comment: `.join` will join without space, you should do a `.join(' ')`

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady Thanks... Friend.. Overconfidence killing me :)

Comment: I was gonna answer the same answer my self, I wouldn't have noticed if i hadn't tested it lol