# Ruby ArgumentError in Each Method

Tags: ruby, loops, instance-methods, argument-error

Ruby Newbie here learning about `each` methods and loops in the full stack online program Bloc. This specific problem has been talked about [before here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28649812/ruby-loops-and-classes-splitting-a-string-into-an-array-and-back-to-a-string-ag), but I'm getting a different error message than that post and I'm not sure why.

In the instructions, the `class StringModifier` "takes a string on initiation" and instance method `proclaim` "splits the string into an array of separate words, adds an exclamation mark to each, then joins them back together with spaces and returns the new string."

I keep receiving an error an `ArgumentError` `wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)` in the irb. I'm not sure where I'm *not* declaring an argument. Isn't that what initializing the `string` variable is for? This is my first question on SO, so any help or point in the right direction would be appreciated. Code and spec script below:

```
class StringModifier
  attr_accessor :string

  def initialize(string)
    @string = string
  end

  def proclaim(string)
    new_array = []
    string.each do |x|
      new_array << "#{x.split(' ').join('!')}"
    end
    new_array
  end
end
```

Here is the spec script:

```
describe StringModifier do
  describe "#proclaim" do
    it "adds an exclamation mark after each word" do
      blitzkrieg_bop = StringModifier.new("Hey ho let's go").proclaim
      expect(blitzkrieg_bop).to eq("Hey! ho! let's! go!")
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `proclaim` method expects the string to be passed in again. This is not needed, since you already store the string on initialization. It also seems your code contained some issues and can be simplified. Try this:

```
class StringModifier
  attr_accessor :string

  def initialize(string)
    @string = string
  end

  def proclaim
    @string.split(' ').join('! ').concat('!')
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, @Drenmi, for clearing up that it's not needed to pass the string again. The error message stops now, but the last word in the string doesn't get the exclamation point. Instead of the result `"Hey! ho! let's! go!"`, it's `"Hey! ho! let's! go"`. Would string interpolation solve that, or running the `each` method on the string?

Comment: @Jay: You can use `.concat` to add an additional exclamation mark to the end of the string:

`@string.split(' ').join('! ').concat('!')`

I have updated the answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. I am going through the Bloc Ruby course myself.

```
class StringModifier
  attr_accessor :string

  def initialize(string)
    @string = string
  end

  def proclaim
    new_array = []
    string.split.each do |word|
      new_array << "#{word}!"
    end
    new_array.join(" ")
  end
end
```